# Why choose Spring Cloud instead of a ready to use Paas (such as Cloud Foundry)?

Tags: openshift, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, paas

I am making some arguments regarding the choice to adopt the Spring Cloud ecosystem with respect to choosing one of the most famous PaaS, ready to use, such as Cloud Foundry or Openshift.

My question is, 
why should I implement my cloud again, from scratch, and not use a ready to use solution?

Thanks for clarifications.

Comment: Spring Cloud is not a PaaS. If you want the features of a PaaS, like being able to deploy code and not worry about the underlying infrastructure then you need a PaaS. Spring Cloud offers many great features and some overlap with those provided by PaaS' like Cloud Foundry, but not all features overlap. Some are quite complementary and help even when running on a PaaS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place more responsibility at the platform it will be more expensive.

That aside, Spring Cloud would make the application more portable, allowing to easily switch your cloud provider.